# Cannot Issue an IOU on Corda-Training-Template Java-Src

Tags: java, corda

The IOUIssueFlow takes a parameter of `IOUState state`. As described in [creating-an-instance-of-a-class](https://docs.corda.net/shell.html#creating-an-instance-of-a-class), we can provide the state object to the flow via the crash shell as (also tried without the dollar sign):

```
flow start IOUIssueFlow$InitiatorFlow state: { amount: $10, lender: "O=ParticipantB, L=New York, C=GB", borrower: "O=ParticipantC, L=Paris, C=FR" }
```

This statement works with the Kotlin version of the corda-training-template but throws the following error in the Java version:

```
No matching constructor found:
- [net.corda.training.state.IOUState]: Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `net.corda.training.state.IOUState` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
```

Although I am not using the default constructor, the default constructor should still be called by `this()`:

```
@ConstructorForDeserialization
    public IOUState(Amount<Currency> amount, Party lender, Party borrower, UniqueIdentifier linearId){
        this.amount = amount;
        this.lender = lender;
        this.borrower = borrower;
        this.linearId = linearId;
    }

    public IOUState(Amount<Currency> amount, Party lender, Party borrower) {
        this(amount, lender, borrower, new UniqueIdentifier());
    }
```

What is the proper syntax to issue an IOU state in the [corda-training-template](https://github.com/corda/corda-training-template)?

Comment: The issue is mostly because of the annotation `@ConstructorForDeserialization`, you would also need to pass a linearId, or just pass a UUID string and create an instance of UniqueIdentifier within the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**start IOUIssueFlow amount: $10, lender: ParticipantB, borrower: ParticipantC**

This should start the desired IOU flow.

Comment: The flow constructor takes only one parameter, the state object:
 
public static class InitiatorFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
  private final IOUState state;
  public InitiatorFlow(IOUState state) {
   this.state = state;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is here `lender: "O=ParticipantB, L=New York, C=**GB**"`. Must be `C=US`